# What do the Death Note shinigami gamble with?

Tags: death-note

In the *Death Note* anime, Ryuk says that in the Shinigami world, there isn't much to do but gamble and be lazy. But if there is nothing of value in the world, what do the shinigami gamble with? What do they bet? Or do they just do it to win for the sake of winning?

Comment: maybe they bet years of their lives like in pirates of the Caribbean where they bet years of servitude?